# A Mysterious Phone Call

Tags: cipher

I've been getting a mysterious phone call everyday at 8 am. And every single day it repeats the exact same message.

> 9874123-------King 
>   1478963654----Dinner
>   741489---------After
>   147854---------Passionately
>   4569874123---Courtyard
>   963256---------The
>   258--------------Yodels
>   987454123----Euclid
>   1475963-------In

The dashes aren't in the actual message, I added them to separate the words from the numbers. I showed it this to my friend and he referred me over to this website. Can you guys decipher this message?

Authors Note: I've been debating whether part of my puzzle is unclear, so I'll just leave you with this hint: Time before Place

Comment: Assuming this isn't real

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Pretty sure his friend wouldn't have to tell him about this website :P (1,043 rep at the time of writing)

Comment: All this nonsense sugar-coating is because of the infamous [what not to do](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) post. People seems happy if the otherwise dry and focused problem is surrounded by random "seems legit" noise.

Comment: @Matsmath Because that so-called "random noise" often contains clues to the nature of the cipher. It's much better to be able to deduce the required methodology from cryptic hints in the surrounding text than to have to make wild random guesses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the numbers

> Consider a standard keypad on a keyboard as shown in the picture 
> [image] 
>  If you trace the shapes made by the numbers in the riddle you seem to get, from top to bottom: 
>  **CArpe dIEM** 
>  So, for example 987454123 corresponds to writing an 'E'.

Also,

> The list of words can be formed into a sentence 
>  "After Dinner, King Euclid Yodels Passionately In The Courtyard" 
>  If we take the letters of our "Carpe Diem" in that order, it spells out 
>  rACEIpMdE 
>  which could be reintepreted as 
>  "Race 1pm, DE" 
>  Perhaps the mysterious caller is challenging you to a race at 1pm in Delaware.

Notes

> It seems like there is more to this riddle and anyone else who'd like to pick it up from here is welcome. I've also seen that the first letters of each of the words can be rearranged to form the phrase "Picket Day" which plays into the whole "Seize the Day" ideology but not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: You found more meaning in my puzzle than I meant to put into it! I wanted the sentence to be "King Euclid yodels passionately after dinner in the courtyard". The first letter of each word spells "keypad" excluding the last three letters.